# mysql column datatype issue for wrong input

Tags: mysql, sql

Sometime,may be unnecessary behavior in column `datatype`.

If I insert more than 4 digits data in `TINYINT` column it insert 255 with out of range warning.

If I want `UPDATE` or `INSERT` string value in `FLOAT` column it makes 0.

But when I try to change negative number in `unsigned datatype`, query is not being execute.

My question is why not stop querying when doesn't match `datatype`  all time . have any idea to stop querying for this type situations?

Comment: Properly verify your data before sending it to the database? The manual clearly states what are the limitation of each datatype, if you are trying to insert wrong data to it you should verify the data first.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you need to manually add error check with the program language you are using. Since once the data going to the database, it is "queried"

Example way to [do error check with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    if (!$mysqli->query("SET a=1")) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you. but you don't know what programming language I use?